# Enumerator assignment

Tags: enums, enumerator, enumerate

I have to convert a float passed into a constructor into a string based off the value of the float (call it R) using an enumerator. It looks something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      float R = 1;
      <name of class> <object> = new <name of class> (R);
    }

 public class <name of class>
 {
   enum <name of enum> {value1 = 1, value2 = 2, value3 = 3}
   float storeR;
   public <name of class>(float R)
 {
   storeR = R;
 }
```

}

How would I go about doing this? Should I place the enum elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is this C#? .net framework 4.5? Yes, you would declare the enum outside of this class, and then parse your value against the enum through `Enum.TryParse()`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx